# problems with screen sizing for app

Tags: android, android-layout, android-screen

So I'm going through the main layout for my app and I have one layout folder "layout" the activity for my app has way to many text views and buttons on it to be able to use a relative layout with moving 1 thing and messing up the entire layout. I've been trying to figure out a way to just force the app into screen compatibility mode with my current layout (frame layout with just using margins) and it's displaying all messed up and nasty.

Does anyone know of a better way to support different screens?

Also, the answer to your first question is:Yes. I have gone through the Supporting multiple screens and screen compatibility mode in the documentation.

Comment: can you post your layout code ?

Answer (score 2):

Use the nested layouts.For 10 inch tablet you have to specify layout-xlarge
For 9 inch tablet specify layout-sw720dp
see the below link for more details
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Ok my problem is that i have the same layout that works with the, "small, large, xlarge" folders, but like, the app isn't using those folders. My developer phone is a Droid Incredible (pretty small screen) and when I put it on my Droid Razr, the layout is all misplaced and what not. its like not taking the layout from the other resources. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

my suggestion is to use nested linear layout and for different screen sizes you have to create different layout folders in your app such as layout_small,layout_large,layout_xlarge,layout_land then copy your xml files into these folders and make changes based on that

Answer (score 0):

Hi williams you can create different layouts for screen sizes such as

layout-large,
 layout-small,
 layout-xlarge ,

So u can manage the screen sizes by creating different layout folders. And then copy your layout XML files to different layouts and you can modify the text fields , buttons ..etc as the screen size .